# How do I remove the remaining code to achieve Blazor code-behind in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, code-behind, blazor

I'm using the example from this outdated video [Introducing Razor Components in ASP.NET Core 3.0 - Daniel Roth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnQ1Vb4fFsk).

The original code looks like this:

```html
@page "/todo"

<h1>Todo (@todoList.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todoList)
    {
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" />
        <input  @bind="todo.Title" />
    </li>
    }
</ul>

<input placeholder="Do something..." @bind="newTodo"/>
<button @onclick="AddTodo">Add</button>

@code {
    IList<TodoItem> todoList = new List<TodoItem>();
    string newTodo;

    void AddTodo()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newTodo))
        {
            todoList.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
            newTodo = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I've added a generic ICollection class to hold the TodoItem class instances, and refactored the code to here:

```html
@page "/todo2"

<h1>Todo2 (@todoColl.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todoColl)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" />
            <input @bind="todo.Title" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<input placeholder="Do something..." @bind="newTodo" />
<button @onclick="@(e => { todoColl.Add(newTodo); newTodo = null;})">Add</button>

@code {
    string newTodo;
    TodoCollection todoColl = new TodoCollection();
}
```

Can I get rid of the remaining two statements in the @code section to achieve full code-behind?
I'd be grateful for any suggestions on improvements.

Comment: "code behind" can  only be achieved with a base class.

Comment: Like this?
    public class TodoItem {...}
    public class TodoCollection : ICollection<TodoItem> {...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need [Base class inheritance for a "code-behind" experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#base-class-inheritance-for-a-code-behind-experience). For your code:

*Pages/Todo.razor*

```
@inherits TodoBase  // <--- inheritance
@page "/todo"

<h1>Todo (@todoList.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todoList)
    {
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" />
        <input  @bind="todo.Title" />
    </li>
    }
</ul>

<input placeholder="Do something..." @bind="newTodo"/>
<button @onclick="AddTodo">Add</button>
```

*TodoBase.vs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class TodoBase : ComponentBase
    {
        // protected for inheritance visibility
        protected IList<TodoItem> todoList = new List<TodoItem>();
        protected string newTodo;

        protected void AddTodo()
        {...}
}
```

Quoting docs:

> Component files mix HTML markup and C# processing code in the same file. The @inherits directive can be used to provide Blazor apps with a "code-behind" experience that separates component markup from processing code.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your suggestion a bit. I kept my TodoItem and TodoCollection classes, and added a new class, TodoBase, derived from ComponentBase. The TodoBase class contains only the two lines that were in the @code section. The razor page lost the @code section and gained an @inherits line.

So, if I want to use Code-behind using multiple classes, I need to create a container class that inherits from ComponentBase, right?